# Matx33f and Mat3f multiplying gives incorrect type

Tags: opencv

I am working on some hobby project where I have essential matrices of size 3x3 and corresponding points m1 and m2.

E is a `cv::Matx3ff` type and m1 `cv::Mat3f`. When I want to multiply them using `E*m1` I get the error

`error: (-215:Assertion failed) type == B.type() in function 'gemm'`

suggesting that the types are different. Therefore I tried

```
cv::Mat(E)*cv::Mat(m1)
```

but still the same error, but both are floats.

It does work if I use standard `Mat`, but it feels like it should be better to use predefined sizes since the dimensions are always known. I have mostly worked with Eigen before, opencv seems to be a bit trickier.

Is the best solution to go to Eigen?

Comment: They are not the same type. The `Matx33f` is matrix `3x3` of `float`s whereas `Mat3f` is a matrix of `Vec3f`. See [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html)

Comment: Yes, but as you can see in my question, I use cv::Mat(E) and cv::Mat(m1) as suggested by others.

Comment: By putting them into the `cv::Mat` you dont change the type. `cv::Mat` is just a container. Resulting matrix is 1-channel in case of `Matx33f` and 3-channel in case of `Mat3f`.